# Проблемы с Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Учился раньше на NetBeans. Решил попробовать один из самых известных компиляторов. Хотел написать простейшую программу, и выводит ошибку.     Библиотеку `#include <iostream>` подключил.
Почему происходит ошибка?

P.S. Без `"stdafx"` все еще хуже. И я не видел в учебниках, что нужно эту библиотеку подключать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "библиотека #include"? И почему вы называете  "stdafx" библиотекой?

Comment: Если вы используете в свой проекте прекомпилированные заголовочные файлы, то перед включением заголовочного файла `stdafx.h` *ничего включать нельзя*. Почему вы вписали `#include <iostream>` *перед* `#include "stdafx.h"`??? Если вы не знаете, что такое прекомпилированные заголовочные файлы и не умеете ими пользоваться, то зачем вы их включили в своем новом проекте?

Comment: @AnT А разве без "stdafx.h" нельзя обойтись ?

Comment: Конечно можно! Выключите нафиг использование прекомпилированных заголовочных файлов в настройках проекта, уберите из кода этот `stdafx.h` и забудьте о нем.

Comment: Меня привела сюда очередь проверок вопросов низкого качества. Несмотря на то что Ваш вопрос на мой взгляд достаточно корректен из за общего тона его так и тянется рука закрыть. Если хотите получать ответы, то пожалуйста постарайтесь впредь формулировать вопросы более нейтрально, не пытаясь распространить вашу фрустрацию на читающих.

Comment: Уважаемые господа, брызжущие слюной. Данный вопрос не из серии "Есть задача по с++...". Человек осваивает новую ide и вещи, кажущиеся вам очевидными, он просто не знает. Не стоит говорить "отключите и забудьте", т.к. pch достаточно полезный и удобный механизм. Всем знакома ситуация бессильного отчаяния, когда ты делаешь все по примеру, а оно не работает. Именно для этого и создан СО, чтобы здесь тебе могли помочь, а не плюнуть свысока фразой про фрустрацию.Вспомните себя, когда вы впервые увидели ide. Будьте человечнее. Как-то так...

Comment: У меня та же проблема! Причем <stda.h> вообще не был включен в код. Всё равно выдает ошибку. Подскажите, что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть некоторый пробел по фундаментальным понятиям С++, таким как препроцессор и директива #include в частности.

Директива `#include` как правило служит для включения заголовочных файлов.
Эти файлы могут содержать определения функций, условия компиляции программы под ту или иную платформу, наборы констант и т.д. Поэтому называть любой файл в кавычках после `#include` библиотекой некорректно. 
Более подробно можно почитать тут:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/18334/blog100.html и тут:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36k2cdd4.aspx

Stdafx.h это специализированный заголовочный файл присущий только для visual studio, о его назначении можно почитать тут:
https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/227521/

В вашем случае вы по незнанию допустили ошибку включив "iostream" перед "stdafx.h", это всегда приводит к ошибкам компиляции.
**Заголовочный файл "stdafx.h" должен включаться в *.c/*.cpp файл самым первым.**

Сохраняйте спокойствие, программирование не всегда просто и понятно, не стесняйтесь гуглить "что такое stdafx.h". Все когда-то начинали и были в схожей ситуации, когда хочется бить клавиатурой по монитору и кричать "какого *** ты не работаешь".
P.S. Для visual studio советую поставить аддон Visual Assist, который значительно упрощает написание кода.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: Не могли бы ли вы мне скинуть ссылку на скачиваниеVisual Assist? Не могу найти нормального сайта, откуда можно скачать.

Comment: @Владислав https://www.wholetomato.com/downloads/default.asp